# How do I use a loop to multiply a row of a 2D array to the column of a second 2D array, and etc in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm learning Java for Uni, and one of the activities our teachers assigned us for homework was to multiply two 2D arrays in a specific way.

[What he wants us to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr5vo.png)

I figured, similar to printing the contents of a 2D array, I could use a for loop to loop through both arrays and add/multiply as necessary. However, I've been scratching my head on how to do it.

I've tried doing this, but this gave me a totally different result.

```
for (int m=0; m<c.length; m++){
    for (int n=0; n<c[m].length; n++){
        c[m][n] = 0;
        for (int o=0; o<c.length; o++){
            c[m][n] += a[n][m]*b[m][n];
        };
    };
};
```

[Result of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnZW2.png)

Writing down each one, and adding/multiplying as necessary seems to work:

```
c[0][0] = (a[0][0]*b[0][0]) + (a[0][1]*b[1][0]) + (a[0][2]*b[2][0]);
c[0][1] = (a[0][0]*b[0][1]) + (a[0][1]*b[1][1]) + (a[0][2]*b[2][1]);
c[0][2] = (a[0][0]*b[0][2]) + (a[0][1]*b[1][2]) + (a[0][2] * b[2][2]);
c[1][0] = (a[1][0]*b[0][0]) + (a[1][1]*b[1][0]) + (a[1][2]*b[2][0]);
c[1][1] = (a[1][0]*b[0][1]) + (a[1][1]*b[1][1]) + (a[1][2]*b[2][1]);
c[1][2] = (a[1][0]*b[0][2]) + (a[1][1]*b[1][2]) + (a[1][2] * b[2][2]);
c[2][0] = (a[2][0]*b[0][0]) + (a[2][1]*b[1][0]) + (a[2][2]*b[2][0]);
c[2][1] = (a[2][0]*b[0][1]) + (a[2][1]*b[1][1]) + (a[2][2]*b[2][1]);
c[2][2] = (a[2][0]*b[0][2]) + (a[2][1]*b[1][2]) + (a[2][2] * b[2][2]);
```

But it's pretty ugly to look at.

Am I wrong for thinking that I could use a for loop?

Comment: Read your code again. How is `o` used?

Comment: @Sneftel, after sleeping on it and reading your comment, I realized that I made a kerfuffle and didn't use `o`. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do your work with this code :

```java
        int size = 3;
        int [][] a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        int [][] b = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        int [][] c = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};;
        
        int total;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                total = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                    total += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
                c[i][j] = total;
            }
        }
```